# Грамматическая основа при числительных

Tags: синтаксис

Помогите разобрать предложения по членам (важна грамматическая основа):

*Пять учебников не хватило на класс. 
Шестьдесят пять миллионов гектаров земель распахано в бассейне Волги.
На морские рубежи приходится около двух третей общей протяженности границ нашей страны.*

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: Пяти учебников **не хватило** на класс. Сказуемое "не хватило" в безличном предложении.

Сравнить: Но чтобы выиграть мир, нам н**е хватило пяти десятилетий.** [Александр Бовин (1999)]

**Количественно-бытийное безличное предложение вида "времени хватает/времени не хватает"**, семантический субъект выражен родительным падежом и не может быть подлежащим.

Материал из книги "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (2013).

Разбор остальных предложений (выделена грамматическая основа):

**Шестьдесят пять миллионов гектаров** земель **распахано** в бассейне Волги. На морские рубежи **приходится** **около двух третей** общей **протяженности** границ нашей страны.